# resize image proportionally with dropzone and javascript load image

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, image-resizing

I'm building an application with Codeigniter 3.0 and I have a form where user can upload several image at the same time using dropzone 3.0. and it's working well until I have to resize and rotate the image according to the EXIF information. which made me had to use Javascript Load Image library, but it won't maintain the aspect ratio even after I add `contain` parameter on the options. I read the [Javascript Load Image docs](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image#image-scaling) but I can't wrap my head around how I'm supposed to do with the returned File object of the `loadImage.scale` function.

can anyone help me with this? or any idea on a simpler way to rotate and resize image while maintaining the proportion on client side?

there's a surprisingly limited amount of documentation (examples/tutorials) for beginners on using dropzone and Javascript Load Image library.. or maybe I'm just too stupid to understand something?

here's my code so far:

**gallery.php**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <div 
        name="upload_gallery"
        id="upload_gallery"
        class="dropzone"
    ></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="filename" id="filename"/>
    <div id="preview_gallery"></div>
</form>
```

**javascript part**

```
var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 800;

$("#upload_gallery").dropzone({
    url: '/review/upload_to_server',
    paramName: "upload_gallery",
    previewContainer: "#preview_gallery",
    autoQueue: false,
    init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this;
        myDropzone.on('addedfile', function(origFile) {
            var options = {
                maxWidth: MAX_WIDTH,
                maxHeight: MAX_HEIGHT,
                orientation: 0,
                contain:true
            }
            loadImage.parseMetaData(
                origFile, 
                function(data) {
                    if (data.exif) {
                        options.orientation = data.exif.get('Orientation');
                    }
                },
                options
            );
            loadImage(
                origFile, 
                function(img) {
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    canvas.width = options.maxWidth;
                    canvas.height = options.maxHeight;

                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, options.maxWidth, options.maxHeight);

                    var resizedFile = base64ToFile(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), origFile);

                    var origFileIndex = myDropzone.files.indexOf(origFile);
                    myDropzone.files[origFileIndex] = resizedFile;

                    myDropzone.enqueueFile(resizedFile);
                },
                options
            );
        });

        myDropzone.on('success', function(file, response, action) {
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            $("#filename").val(response.new_filename);
        });
    }
});
```

**PHP file**

```
public function upload_to_server()
{
    $result = array(
        'new_filename' => '',
        'message' => '',
    );
    $upload_dir = './assets/img/';
    if ( ! file_exists($upload_dir))
    {
        mkdir($upload_dir, 0777, true);
    }

    mt_srand();
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo(basename($_FILES['upload_gallery']['name']), PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $encrypted_filename = md5(uniqid(mt_rand())).'.'.$ext;

    $config['upload_path']      = $upload_dir;
    $config['file_name']        = $encrypted_filename;
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|png|jpg';
    $config['file_ext_tolower'] = TRUE;
    $config['max_size']         = 2048;
    $config['detect_mime']      = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('upload_gallery'))
    {
        $result['new_filename'] = $encrypted_filename;
    }
    else
    {
        $result['message'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

**EDIT**

found the solution at midnight.. seriously. it turns out that I just needed to calculate the canvas' dimension by changing this part:

```
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    canvas.width = options.maxWidth;
                    canvas.height = options.maxHeight;

                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, options.maxWidth, options.maxHeight);
```

into this

```
                        var width = img.width;
                        var height = img.height;

                        // hitung dimensi resize
                        if (width > height) {
                            if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                                height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                                width   = MAX_WIDTH;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                                width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                                height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                            }
                        }

                        // convert menjadi File Object
                        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                        canvas.width = width;
                        canvas.height = height;

                        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
```

hope this helps a wandering soul somewhere..